# load .php file in div with ajax (wordpress)

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a script that shows a box after i clicked a download link in my single page (this works).

I also want it to load a test.php in a certain div. But for some reason it will not work. test.php is located in my theme folder. Even when I try to ad it to my root it won't work.

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
        $("body").click(function(e) {
                if (e.target.id == "contentblock" || $(e.target).parents("#contentblock").size()) {
                    //alert("Inside div");
                    if ($(e.target).is("a")) {
                        $('#afterdownload').fadeIn('slow');
                        $('#ajax').load('test.php');
                    }
                });
            <?php ?>
        }
        }
        });
        })   
        </script>

    <div id="ajax"></div>
```

The test.php file contains this

```
    <h1>test</h1>
    <p>You downloaded Post: <?php the_ID(); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to echo the full path of the theme:

```
$('#ajax').load('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/test.php');
```

Additionally, make sure jQuery is loaded first before running:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't load anything.

Even 
        $('#ajax').load('wp-content/themes/papercraftplazaV2/test.php'); doesn't work either.

Comment: Check your console log and see if you're getting a '$ is not defined' error. jQuery should be loaded before the script runs. You can try adding a listener to make sure document loads before running. I've edited my answer above.

Comment: OOps just had some extra } in there that shouldn't be there!

It works!